# How to add column into scaffold in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I have run the command

```
rails g scaffold article
```

and forget get to pass column name now how can i add column to my `article` table.

Answer (score 2):

You can either

- undo your scaffold with

```
rails d scaffold article
```

and re-do it with the missing field (cf. https://www.rubyguides.com/2020/03/rails-scaffolding/)

- or you can run a migration afterwards to add the missing column to your article table:

```
rails g migration add_title_to_article name:string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add your column with a new migration. You run the migration with the name of column you want to adds and then declare the data type after the migration command. The command to add name is as below:

```
rails g migration AddNameToArticle name:string
```

This can also be done as @Guilaume Bihet stated.

```
rails g migration add_name_to_article name:string
```